# Non-parametric Multivariate Linear Regression in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I'm attempting to do some multivariate linear regressions on 3 features I've extracted from some brain imaging data (linked via joint ICA).

```
Analysis of Variance Table

                               Df   Pillai approx F num Df den Df     Pr(>F)
(Intercept)                     1 0.767709 196.0939      3    178 < 2.22e-16
Sex_Code                        1 0.076616   4.9230      3    178 0.00261091
Age_Centered                    1 0.175675  12.6447      3    178 1.5668e-07
Education                       1 0.005479   0.3269      3    178 0.80590934
RaceCode                        5 0.072561   0.8923     15    540 0.57297994
Ethnic_Category_Code            2 0.008003   0.2397      6    358 0.96317002
Adj_MCCB                        1 0.094521   6.1937      3    178 0.00050167
Ethnic_Category_Code:Adj_MCCB   1 0.009814   0.5881      3    178 0.62359393
Residuals                     180

(Intercept)                   ***
Sex_Code                      **
Age_Centered                  ***
Education
RaceCode
Ethnic_Category_Code
Adj_MCCB                      ***
Ethnic_Category_Code:Adj_MCCB
Residuals
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, I've noticed that a lot of the assumptions for my models (multivariate normality and heteroscedasticity in particular) are violated so I'm trying to find a non-parametric alternative for my model.

```
$multivariateNormality
             Test        Statistic              p value Result
1 Mardia Skewness 586.829925382144 1.28223054431529e-62     NO
2 Mardia Kurtosis 13.7011451636548                    0     NO
3             MVN             <NA>                 <NA>     NO

$univariateNormality
          Test  Variable Statistic   p value Normality
1 Shapiro-Wilk  Column1     0.9818   0.013      NO
2 Shapiro-Wilk  Column2     0.9733   0.001      NO
3 Shapiro-Wilk  Column3     0.9509  <0.001      NO
4 Shapiro-Wilk  Column4     0.5058  <0.001      NO
5 Shapiro-Wilk  Column5     0.6164  <0.001      NO
6 Shapiro-Wilk  Column6     0.9949  0.7603      YES
7 Shapiro-Wilk  Column7     0.9676  0.0002      NO
8 Shapiro-Wilk  Column8     0.7960  <0.001      NO
```

I've attempted some of the common R packages in a multivariate framework (e.g. adonis, predictmeans, lmPerm, permuco, and some others), but the only one that seems to avoid throwing errors in multivariate/multiple DV models is lmp from lmPerm:

`summary(aov(lmp(Feature1 ~ Sex_Code + Age_Centered + Education + RaceCode + Ethnic_Category_Code + Adj_MCCB, data=MACIP_Inputs)))`

However, it does not appear to produce the Hotelling's T or Pilai's Trace metrics necessary for multivariate conclusions, and only prints the Univariate regression and/or anova tables.

```
[1] "Settings:  unique SS : numeric variables centered"
 Response 1 :
                      Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq  F value     Pr(>F)
Sex_Code               1 0.168176 0.1681765 11.41478 0.00089219 ***
Age_Centered           1 0.093938 0.0939382  6.37594 0.01242651 *
Education              1 0.012906 0.0129064  0.87600 0.35054556
RaceCode               5 0.088713 0.0177426  1.20426 0.30894398
Ethnic_Category_Code   2 0.006244 0.0031219  0.21189 0.80925227
Adj_MCCB               1 0.137672 0.1376719  9.34432 0.00257563 **
Residuals            181 2.666714 0.0147332
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response 2 :
                      Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq  F value       Pr(>F)
Sex_Code               1 0.004929 0.0049287  0.60451   0.43787687
Age_Centered           1 0.187001 0.1870009 22.93588 0.0000034727 ***
Education              1 0.001859 0.0018588  0.22798   0.63360181
RaceCode               5 0.022029 0.0044057  0.54037   0.74550747
Ethnic_Category_Code   2 0.000001 0.0000005  0.00006   0.99993883
Adj_MCCB               1 0.112240 0.1122396 13.76632   0.00027528 ***
Residuals            181 1.475729 0.0081532
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response 3 :
                      Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
Sex_Code               1 0.000113 0.0001131 0.01040 0.918877
Age_Centered           1 0.102365 0.1023646 9.41500 0.002483 **
Education              1 0.001186 0.0011859 0.10908 0.741579
RaceCode               5 0.046066 0.0092131 0.84738 0.517834
Ethnic_Category_Code   2 0.012942 0.0064711 0.59518 0.552541
Adj_MCCB               1 0.001824 0.0018240 0.16776 0.682594
Residuals            181 1.967922 0.0108725
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Does anyone know of a decent out-of-the-box non-parametric multivariate linear regression package?

If not, does anyone have suggestions on how to do such an analysis in some of the packages listed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not try robust methods such as [quantile regression](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=quantreg)?

Comment: So I tried quantile regression with multiple DVs and it threw the following:


`rq(GM_Feature_1 ~ Sex_Code + Age_Centered + Education + RaceCode + Ethnic_Category_Code*Adj_MCCB, data=MACIP_Inputs)`

`Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix`

Comment: It'll work with the interaction removed (but I want the interaction), and it won't produce the ANOVA table:

`Warning message:
In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique`
`Error in anova.rq(greg) :
  Anova is only defined (yet) for lists of rq objects`
`lou <- rq(GM_Feature_1 ~ 1, data=MACIP_Inputs)`
`Error in solve.default((V[[1]])[nullH, nullH], (coef[[1]])[nullH]) :
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.00852e-54
In addition: Warning message:
In summary.rq(x, se = se, R = R, covariance = TRUE) : 2 non-positive fis`

Comment: I've actually tried ALL of the models detailed here to no avail:
https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_12.html

Comment: To have the ANOVA table you must also fit the null model, `model.null <- rq(GM_Feature_1 ~ 1, data = MACIP_Inputs, tau = 0.5)`. Then, `anova(model.full, model.null)` where `model.full` is the model you want fit.

Comment: So I didn't actually get to that point. Feature1 (the thing I'm actually interested in) is actually a cbind array of 3 DVs and that throws the following:

`rq(Feature1 ~ Sex_Code + Age_Centered + Education + RaceCode + Ethnic_Category_Code*Adj_MCCB, data=MACIP_Inputs)
Error in y - x %*% z$coef : non-conformable arrays`

Comment: If the regression is giving that error, I would try to fit three separate models and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Seems to run just fine if it's 3 separate models. But at that point I'd probably be better off just running 3 local regressions or GAMs right?